# Reference Command Line Argument to in Spring Batch Step

Tags: java, spring, string, arguments, spring-batch

I have setup my main class to take arguments (fileName) but cant seem to get a step to work without hard coding a file path. I did the same thing with another step using the @Value annotationand it worked fine but i cant seem to use it here but it doesn't work. I want to replace the `IBMIA0` file path.

Main Class

```
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            log.error("ERROR: No Arguments Passed");
            throw new ADESystemException("ERROR: No Arguments Passed", null);
        }
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis())
                .addString("fileName", args[1]).toJobParameters();
        if ("SYNC".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])) {
            jobLauncher.run(processSynceJob, jobParameters);
    }
}
```

Job Config

```
    @Bean
    public SyncsortRowValidationTask syncsortRowValidationTask (@Value("#{jobParameters[fileName]}") String fileName){
        return new SyncsortRowValidationTask(fileName);
    }

....

 @Bean
    public Step syncRowValidation() {
        return almBatchConfig.stepBuilder.get("syncRowValidation").tasklet(syncsortRowValidationTask("C:\\input\\IBMIA0")).build();
    }
 @Bean
    public Job processSyncJob() {
        return BatchConfig.jobs.get("processSyncJob")
                .start(syncRowValidation())
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `syncsortRowValidationTask` bean step scoped:

```
@Bean
@StepScoped
public SyncsortRowValidationTask syncsortRowValidationTask (@Value("#{jobParameters[fileName]}") String fileName){
    return new SyncsortRowValidationTask(fileName);
}
```

Please refer to the [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section of the reference documentation for more details.